# FindViewById can access elements from all layouts without SetContentView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I am currently working on a small Xamarin project for android and I've noticed that I can use FindViewById to access any button,spinner, etc from any layout in my project.

This still applies even if I remove all instances of SetContentView from my project.

Am I misunderstanding where and how FindViewById locates and has access to layouts? I would like to ensure my activities only have access to a single layout that I specify

For Example:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout123);

var next = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.next);
var save = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.save);
```

How do I ensure that I only grab the next and save buttons from layout123 and not layout234?

Edit: Answered by @apineda in chat. Turns out that it has to do with VS not picking up on the errors in debug, but on application run the errors would pop up as expected.

Comment: That's the way `FindViewById` works. It does search in the Layout you set but the Ids you get from **Resource.Id** are part of the Android Global Resource ID file. This is why if you don't set content before using `FindViewById` or if the Id you are finding it's not part of the Layout you set in the `SetContentView` method the result will be **Null**

Comment: So should me using SetContentView(Resource.ID.mylayout) limit FindViewById to only those within the layout or am I still misunderstanding? @apineda

Comment: `SetContentView` tells `FindViewById` **where** to search. If you don't set one your result will always be **Null**. Or if you set a Layout that does not contain the Id you pass in the method it will also be **Null** meaning it did not find what you asked to search

Comment: Interesting, because even with setcontentview(Resource.Id.layout123) I can still access any element from any layout with FindViewById in my program. That is what is concerning me. I would expect it to be null as you've said. @apineda

Comment: Weird. So that means that if you create new Layout let's call it **layout546** and inside there you add a button with Id **mynicebutton** are you able to access it with the code above?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/SS6Coxj) All of the items in the screenshot shouldn't be found. Also Rebuilding the solution succeeds with everything except myspecialbutton @apineda

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186882/discussion-between-apineda-and-daniel-dees).

Comment: When do you call `SetContentView` and what do you expect it to do? In your Activity are you having multiple calls to it? If so, why?